# What is the easiest way or tool to format Json String?

Tags: java, json

What is the easiest way to format Json String before I post it to StackOverflow?

I don't want to format it manually and most online sites only validate Json but do not format.

From:

```
[{"lines":{"0": "Hammersmith & City","1": "Circle"},"id": "233","name": "Shepherd's Bush Market"},{"lines": {"0": "Hammersmith & City","1": "Circle"},"id": "233","name": "Shepherd's Bush Market"},{"lines": {"0": "Hammersmith & City","1": "Circle"},"id": "233","name": "Shepherd's Bush Market"}]
```

I want to make it like:

```
    [{
    "lines": {
        "0": "Hammersmith & City",
        "1": "Circle"
    },
    "id": "233",
    "name": "Shepherd's Bush Market"
},
{
    "lines": {
        "0": "Hammersmith & City",
        "1": "Circle"
    },
    "id": "233",
    "name": "Shepherd's Bush Market"
},
{
    "lines": {
        "0": "Hammersmith & City",
        "1": "Circle"
    },
    "id": "233",
    "name": "Shepherd's Bush Market"
}]
```

Thank you,

**[EDIT]**

There is no reference to java but this question would be actual for java(Android) developers

Comment: Your *from* string is different from your result. The [ may be invalid.

Comment: yes, fixed, added it manually as example

Comment: ??? I see many online formatters choking on your [ and your '' . http://jsonlint.com/ does not accept your JSON as valid! Rewrite your Q and A with valid JSON. Your statement that 'many online sites do not properly format' is likely because your JSON is invalid.

Comment: @JanDoggen sorry, now you ca ncheck

Comment: I've been using `jsonlint.com` the whole time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSONEditorOnline](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/) does the trick perfectly. You have to make sure your JSON is valid, but the site will tell you when it's not (And yes, some other formatter sites don't work **without telling you why** when the JSON is invalid)

Answer (score 3):

I saw a lot of questions based on Json parsing.

Some questions users post Json as is:

or in one row, like:

```
[{"lines":{"0": "Hammersmith & City","1": "Circle"},"id": "233","name": "Shepherd's Bush Market"},{"lines": {"0": "Hammersmith & City","1": "Circle"},"id": "233","name": "Shepherd's Bush Market"},{"lines": {"0": "Hammersmith & City","1": "Circle"},"id": "233","name": "Shepherd's Bush Market"}]
```

or try to format Json string manually like:

```
[{"lines":{"0": "Hammersmith & City","1": "Circle"},
"id": "233","name": "Shepherd's Bush Market"},
{"lines": {"0": "Hammersmith & City","1": "Circle"},
"id": "233","name": "Shepherd's Bush Market"},
{"lines": {"0": "Hammersmith & City","1": "Circle"},
"id": "233","name": "Shepherd's Bush Market"}]
```

It's sadly when user can't solve the issue only because Json string not formatted good and he doesn't know is it Array or Object.

Anyways There is an easy way by using `Notepad++`

- Open Notepad++
- Open Plugin Manager like:

[image]

- in "Available" tab select `JSON viewer`

[image]

Install it and restart Notapad++

When done, you can format Json, like:

[image]

Now you have formatted Json and you ready to post it to your question.

```
[{
    "lines": {
        "0": "Hammersmith & City",
        "1": "Circle"
    },
    "id": "233",
    "name": "Shepherd's Bush Market"
},
{
    "lines": {
        "0": "Hammersmith & City",
        "1": "Circle"
    },
    "id": "233",
    "name": "Shepherd's Bush Market"
},
{
    "lines": {
        "0": "Hammersmith & City",
        "1": "Circle"
    },
    "id": "233",
    "name": "Shepherd's Bush Market"
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Google chrome has got a very nice extension called `JSON Formatter` that formats your `json string` in to actual `json` format. It also tells if any error in your `JSON` string.

here is the [link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-formatter/pblpfhfcojodgcifojnofommahgbaple?hl=en-US)

Comment: This is a reason why I posted this question to find other easy solution. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [Formatter JSON](http://wtools.io/check/validate/json), this is powerful tool who can validate and make beautiful your JSON.